# How to strip metadata from a video file with reliable/reproducable results?

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata, mp4

I'm trying to find a clean way to produce "just the raw data" from a variety of media files.  By this I mean, to take a file, `test.mp4` and strip all of the metadata/headers off it so I can then generate a hash of the actual video data.

After a lot of digging on this subject, ffmpeg seems to be my best shot at this, but the command I found to do the metadata stripping, appears to *produce different results depending on the version of ffmpeg*, which leads me to think that either (a) I've got the incantation wrong, or (b) ffmpeg isn't actually returning just the raw data.

To test for this, I used [jrottenberg's ffmpeg Docker containers](https://hub.docker.com/r/jrottenberg/ffmpeg/) to create a hash of the same file across multiple ffmpeg versions:

```
for tag in 4.0-centos 4.0-alpine 3.4-alpine 3.4-centos 3.0-alpine 3.0-centos; do
    docker pull jrottenberg/ffmpeg:${tag}
    docker run --rm \
      -v /data/:/data/ \
      -it jrottenberg/ffmpeg:${tag} \
      -i /data/test.mp3 \
      -map_metadata -1 -c:v copy -c:a copy \
      -f mp4 - | md5sum
done
```

The result was that every one of these instances had a different hash output (Docker output truncated for clarity):

```
d7e3577ffe65d73240f48842e8d42207  -
da2bda81911d758c877aace6ed3c0025  -
ed24948c1dedf5d53870dfcfe24c7c70  -
3dbb89d812c26711a33ca670403ccc20  -
a4533446d3225e755eb041167e32b279  -
69a51d82acc9987eed8b517a748435eb  -
```

So my question: is there a more reliable way to do this?  Did I just miss an option for ffmpeg?  Am I missing something here, or is ffpeg just not a good tool for this job?  If not that, what *is* a good choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Generating a hash

Use the [hash muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#hash-1) to return a hash of the raw decoded data:

```
$ ffmpeg -loglevel error -i input.mp3 -f hash -f null -
SHA256=727ef2f1a4317a97ddb9aa83e80b5d876986a92c67045317bffb6505e4de6617
```

Use the [`-map` option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) to select the desired stream(s).

Example to generate a hash of the first audio stream only and output MD5 hash:

```
$ ffmpeg -loglevel error -i input.foo -map 0:a:0 -f hash -hash MD5 -
MD5=616beb5bf16504caf37aacf0d0e99731
```

Metadata will not influence the returned hash (unless you consider album art metadata, your MP3 contains it, and your ffmpeg command doesn't exclude it).

## Raw data

> Barring simply using the SHA256 hash instead, is there a way to get the raw data rather than just a hash of it?

You can output raw video:

```
ffmpeg -i input -f rawvideo output
```

Or pipe it:

```
ffmpeg -i input -f rawvideo -
```

Both video and audio into separate output files `outvideo` and `outaudio`:

```
ffmpeg -i input -map 0:v:0 -f rawvideo outvideo -map 0:a:0 -f s16le outaudio
```

Comment: Ooh, this is handy, but it leaves me with one additional problem: I don't *just* want a hash, but rather I want to use the data to generate a signature with a private key.  Barring simply using the SHA256 hash instead, is there a way to get the raw data rather than just a hash of it?

Comment: @DanielQuinn I guess I misunderstood what you wanted. Assumed it was an x/y problem that you just wanted a hash of the decoded data. See updated answer.

Comment: I would suggest a different tack. Using rawvideo and pcm formats forces decoding. Should the decoders change (usually to correct fuzzing-detected issues), so could the hash. Suggest, `ffmpeg -i input -map 0:v:0 -c copy -f data outvideo -map 0:a:0 -c copy -f data outaudio`

Comment: Thank you to both of you!  I had no idea that ffmpeg was so versitile!